# Javascript Slideshow Last Image Appearing Quickly at Start of Show

Tags: javascript

I have created a 4-image fading slideshow.  When the page loads, the last image flashes quickly before the first image appears.  I tried using a blank image at the end as suggested in a post on this site, but that had no effect.  I also tried putting the first slide in the last position as well which removes the flashing image at start, but then the last image appears for twice as long.  Is there a way to keep this from happening without having to duplicate the first slide?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#photos img:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() {
        var current = $('#photos img:visible');
        var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : $('#photos img:eq(0)');  
        //hide the current image  
        current.fadeOut(2000);  
        //show the next one  
        next.fadeIn(2000);  
    }, 5000);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hide the image with css, this way it hidden before the js has loaded, something like this:

```
//css
#photos img:last-child {
     display: none;
}
```

Just an idea...

**Edit** from your comments.

```
#photos img {
     display: none;
}
#photos img:first-child {
     display: block;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but the last image still flashes.  I also tried this for the last slide, but that had no effect either.
<img src="images/reGoldSignup/slide4.jpg" alt="Brokers" style="display:none"/>

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this forum and can't get the code to format correctly in the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to hide all the images except the first one.  When I hid only one, another one would appear instead, but it was so quick I thought it was the same one.  Now it's working fine.